# API or database to load data for Country, State/province/region, and city select menus

Tags: javascript, html, database, json, api

anyone know of a solution? i have found online a select menu for countries, but i need either an API or a database with every state/province and major city in each country.

Comment: Are you asking for an API, or for a database of cities and states?

Comment: Brilliant idea 21029 of mine was to provide a web service for exactly this problem... plus timezones. Just haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: I am using this and works great !! 
https://www.universal-tutorial.com/rest-apis/free-rest-api-for-country-state-city

Comment: https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database

Countries States Cities Database

Full Database of city state country available in JSON, SQL, XML, YAML & CSV format. All Countries, States & Cities are Covered & Populated with Different Combinations & Versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). You can download (just about) everything they have and create your own local databases, or you can use their REST [Webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) API. As an added bonus, they even have already made [client libraries](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want users to be able to select a location, you could use a search-based interface such as [OSM Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). You can download the data and install it yourself, or just use their web services (subject to usage limits). Indeed, you might be able to download the Nominatim database and write a different API to use menus to drill down.