# is there any free api which i can use to load list of countries states cities etc dynamically may be from Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I want to make a website where in the drop down for countries states cities can be filled by ajax call. But I don't want to keep all these values on my local database. Please suggest possible data sources. If possible a jsfiddle will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [API or database to load data for Country, State/province/region, and city select menus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659269/api-or-database-to-load-data-for-country-state-province-region-and-city-select)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about data source recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) for such requirements )

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Looking into your suggested web link

Comment: just started playing around looks like this is what I was looking for. Thanks :)