# Getting all States/Region/Cities when passing Country name

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, api

i am creating a web application in java using spring where i have to populate all states/region/cities in a drop down when choosing a country. Is there any api, web-service or javascript for achieving the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Yanick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320700/yanick-rochon) specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659269/api-or-database-to-load-data-for-country-state-province-region-and-city-select);

> Take a look at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). You can download (just about) everything they
>   have and create your own local databases, or you can use their [REST
>   Webservice API](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html). As an added bonus, they even have already made [client
>   libraries](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html).

Also you can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va).